# Combobox doesnt pass the value from the view to the model ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, view

I want to pass the value of the combobox to my variable in the model. Here is the code in the View:

```
 <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Register">
            <div class="flex-item flex-item1">   
                                    <label asp-for="@Model.tournamentID"></label>
                               <select id="tournament" name="tournament" asp-for="tournamentID">
                    @if (Model.listOfTournaments != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var tournament in Model.listOfTournaments)
                        {
                            <option value="@tournament.id" selected="@(ViewBag.SelectedIndex==tournament.id?"selected":null)" >@tournament.id</option>
                        }
                    }
                    </select>
                 </div>
            <div class="flex-item flex-item2">info</div>
            <div class="flex-item flex-item3">message</div>
            <div class="flex-item flex-item4">checkbox</div>
            <div class="flex-item flex-item5">          
                <div class="flex-item flex-item3">
                    <input type="submit" value="Register for Tournament" /> 
                </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

And the code in the Model:

```
        TournamentManager tournamentManager = new TournamentManager();
        public List<Tournament> listOfTournaments = new List<Tournament>();
        [BindProperty]
        public int tournamentID { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            foreach (Tournament t in tournamentManager.GetTournaments())
            {
                listOfTournaments.Add(t);
            }
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {

            var id = Convert.ToInt32(User.FindFirst(x => x.Type == "ID").Value);
            tournamentManager.RegisterPlayer(tournamentID, id);
        }
```

After I select for example 8 in the combobox, I want in the model the tournamentID value to be also 8. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After I select for example 8 in the combobox, I want in the model the
> tournamentID value to be also 8.

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {           
        TournamentManager tournamentManager = new TournamentManager();
        public List<Tournament> listOfTournaments = new List<Tournament>();
        [BindProperty]
        public int tournamentID { get; set; }

        public SelectList ListOfTournaments { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            //foreach (Tournament t in tournamentManager.GetTournaments())
            //{
            //    listOfTournaments.Add(t);
            //}

            listOfTournaments = new List<Tournament>
            {
                new Tournament{ id = 1},
                new Tournament{ id = 2},
                new Tournament{ id = 3},
                new Tournament{ id = 4}, 
                new Tournament{ id = 5},
                new Tournament{ id = 6},
                new Tournament{ id = 7},
                new Tournament{ id = 8}
            };

            ListOfTournaments = new SelectList(listOfTournaments, nameof(Tournament.id), nameof(Tournament.id));
            
        }

        public void OnPost(int tournamentID)
        {

            //var id = Convert.ToInt32(User.FindFirst(x => x.Type == "ID").Value);
            //tournamentManager.RegisterPlayer(tournamentID, id);
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<form method="post">
            <div class="flex-item flex-item1">   
                                 
            <select asp-for="tournamentID" asp-items="Model.ListOfTournaments">
             <option value=""></option>
            </select>
              
            </div>
            <div class="flex-item flex-item2">info</div>
            <div class="flex-item flex-item3">message</div>
            <div class="flex-item flex-item4">checkbox</div>
            <div class="flex-item flex-item5">          
                <div class="flex-item flex-item3">
                    <input type="submit" value="Register for Tournament" /> 
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Result:

[image]